# Sorting select sheets between specific sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has four 'system' sheets and each system sheet has a dynamic number or subsequent tabs used for various data collection.  What I need is a way to sort the systems and their children sheets in alphabetical order but existing between two specific sheets.  Example:

> [Intro/Reference Sheet] [Customer info Sheet] **[System 1] [Sys1 Child 1-12] [System 2] [Sys2 Child 1-12] [System 3] [Sys3 Child 1-12] [System 4] [Sys4 1-12]** [Other sheets]

I've tried sorting subs such as

```
For Each w1 In Sheets
 For Each w2 In Sheets
  If w1.Range("Z1") <> "" And w2.Range("Z1") <> "" Then
   If w2.Range("Z1").Value < w1.Range("Z1").Value Then
    If w2.Range("Z1").Value = "S1L0" Then
     w2.Move after:=Cover
    Else
     w2.Move before:=w1
    End If
   End If
  End If
 Next w2
Next w1
```

It starts to work great but then the loop gets out of hand and I have the one sheet with "S1L0" in the target range where it should be and everything else is at the end of the list.  Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

EDIT:
The system sheets all begin with "S1" to "S4" but they get renamed to "S1 - %string%" to "S4 - %string%", the children sheet are copies of a hidden sheet that are named initially "S#L#" where the # is the system and the child number respectively. the children sheets can also be renamed but it will follow the pattern "S#L# - %string%"

Comment: Without your relevant data sample it's quite difficult to realize what's wrong.

Comment: Can you give more details about how you go about deciding which sheet is which - it seems you look at range "Z1", but you don't give the specific rules you've implemented to know which is a system / child sheet...

Comment: I apologize, the system sheets all begin with "S1" to "S4" but they get renamed to "S1 - %string%" to "S4 - %string%", the children sheet are copies of a hidden sheet that are named initially "S#L#" where the # is the system and the child number respectively.  the children sheets can also be renamed but it will follow the pattern "S#L# - %string%"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Sub SortSheets()
    Dim lngParentID As Long, lngChildID As Long
    Dim wsParent As Worksheet, wsChild As Worksheet, wsLast As Worksheet

    Set wsLast = Sheets("Customer Info Sheet")
    For lngParentID = 1 To 4
        Set wsParent = GetSheet(lngParentID)
        If Not wsParent Is Nothing Then
            wsParent.Move After:=wsLast
            Set wsLast = wsParent

            For lngChildID = 1 To 12
                Set wsChild = GetSheet(lngParentID, lngChildID)
                If Not wsChild Is Nothing Then
                    wsChild.Move After:=wsLast
                    Set wsLast = wsChild
                End If
            Next lngChildID
        End If
    Next lngParentID
End Sub

Private Function GetSheet(lngParentID As Long, Optional lngChildID As Long = 0) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        If (lngChildID = 0 And (ws.Name = "S" & lngParentID Or Left(ws.Name, 4) = "S" & lngParentID & " -")) Or _
            Left(ws.Name, 5) = "S" & lngParentID & "L" & Format(lngChildID, "00") Then
            Set GetSheet = ws
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: It starts strong but it finishes up by putting all of the parent sheets in order separate from the children sheet.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The resulting order should be S1, S1L1, S1L2, S2, S2L1, ... Is that not the case?

Comment: No, it will sort the S1 series, (S1, S1L1, S1L2, etc) then the S2s, when the S2 series is sorted it takes S2 and places it after S1 leaving S2L1, S2L2, etc after S1L1,S1L2, etc.  Pattern repeats with S3 and S4. I'm left with S1, S2, S3, S4, S1L1, S2L1, S3L1, S4L1

Comment: I wonder if there's an issue with the two digit child ID, there should be a leading zero if it's < 10.  Running through the locals it doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: that might be the case! if the names contain a leading 0, replace `Left(ws.Name, 4) = "S" & lngParentID & "L" & lngChildID` with `Left(ws.Name, 5) = "S" & lngParentID & "L" & Format(lngChildID,"00")`. Else, please send me your workbook (see my profile

Comment: Yup that sure was the fix, thanks a whole lot!  Not only did I get that solved, I learned the format function too!